# xsl:value-of Not Working

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am having a little issue this piece of code in my Xsl.

```
<xsl:if test="ShippingName != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="border:none;" align="right">
                        <strong>Shipping Via</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ShippingName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
```

It passes the test condition (ShippingName != '') and assigns the style to 'td' but at the point where I am displaying the value that this element contains (), it displays nothing.

Any ideas why this could be happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for this behavior is that the string value of `ShippingName` consists only of whitespace characters.

**Solution**:

**Either use**:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="ShippingName"/>
```

**or replace**:

```
<xsl:if test="ShippingName != ''">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(ShippingName)">
```

The standard XPath function [**`normalize-space`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) produces a new string from its argument `someString` in which all leading and trailing whitespace is discarded and any inter-whitespace is replaced by a single space character. In case `someString` consists only of whitespace characters, they all are discarded and the test for an empty sting is `false()`, because by definition `boolean('')` is `false()`.

Comment: Ok so reading your post, I replaced the first line of my code to what you posted, but since then it not even prints "Shipping Via", itdoes n't seem to come into that block of code, test condition is failing. Also I tried hardcoding value into ShippingName to make sure there are no White-Space characters but to no avail.

Comment: It's working for me on the rest of there element names if just this one that having issues I couldn't seem to figure out.

Comment: Ok, that's fixed. I figured out an hours of debugging that ShippingName was being replaced within the whole process I wrote. Thanks for your help though, I didn't know those methods you told me :)